# Calculating the Black-Scholes Implied Volatility for Intraday Data in SAS

Tags: sas

Sorry for possibly asking a very basic question. I am quite new to coding in SAS.
As I can see there is a standard SAS FCMP procedure to calculate the Black Scholes Implied Volatility for individual option data.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003193738.htm

But my problem is that I have a data table of intraday option trading data that lists all the required fields, i.e. strike price, time to expiry, equity price, interest rate and volatility. Is there any way i can code so that I can calculate the implied volatility for these individual entries.

I understand that possibly i need to use some kind of loop to do so, but i am not able to understand how to pass values within procedures in SAS. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to post what you've tried. I would suggest looking into PROC FCMP first and see how to specify parameters instead of fixed values as it uses.

Comment: you can also post on communities.sas.com for more help